# find one criteria in my file and print the whole line python

Tags: python, file, search, printing

```
def beginner():
    fileName = "classmarks.csv"

    myfile = open(fileName, "r")
    userResults = []
    if "beginner" in line 
        print (line) 
    myfile.close()
```

this is my attempt at it but I am not sure if this works and am looking to find a better way to do this function

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
def beginner():
    fileName = "classmarks.csv"

    with open(fileName, "r") as fobj:
        data = fobj.readlines()
        for line in data:
            if "beginner" in line:
                print(line)
```

Comment: ill try that now

Comment: the as doesn't seem to work as it comes up invalid syntax

Comment: It is correct syntax though. Did you modify your code? The code he gave you wont just work like this.

Comment: @ConnorHenry: which invalid syntax?

Comment: iv entered my file name the reset im not sure what to change

Comment: @HarshaBiyani You don't have to use readlines(). You can use `fobj` to check file contents like this : `for line in fobj`